New-ADUser and Hyphenated Last Names
I have used a new user setup script to quickly speed up account creation for what feels like eons but we have our first onboard that has a hyphenated last name and my script keeps throwing 'New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name' errors (likely when it gets to the -Name parameter). The script works fine when a non-hyphenated last name is entered.
My question for the experts is, since -Name sets the name attribute, is there a way to either escape the last name hyphen or to otherwise fix -Name so that when it adds the attribute to AD that it enters $FirstName $MiddleInitial. $LastName so it's consistent with the rest of my AD users?
My script (sanitized):
$DefaultPassword = 'DefaultPassword'
$FirstName = Read-Host -Prompt 'First Name: '
$MiddleInitial = Read-Host -Prompt 'Middle Initial: '
$LastName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Last Name: '
$Name = "$FirstName $MiddleInitial. $LastName"
$DisplayName = $Name
$Username = "$FirstName.$LastName"
$UserPrincipalName = "$FirstName.$LastName@domain.com"
$Title = Read-Host -Prompt 'Title: '
$Company = "CompanyName"
$EmailAddress = $UserPrincipalName
$StreetAddress = "Address"
$City = "City"
$State = "State"
$PostalCode = "Zip"
$Country = "Country"
$proxyAddress = @{ProxyAddresses = "SMTP:$UserPrincipalName,smtp:$Username@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com" -split ","}

New-ADUser `
    -Path "OU=Users Location,OU=Special OU for Users,DC=domain,DC=local" `
    -Name $Name `
    -GivenName $FirstName `
    -Initials $MiddleInitial `
    -Surname $LastName `
    -SamAccountName $Username `
    -DisplayName $DisplayName `
    -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $DefaultPassword -Force) `
    -Title $Title `
    -Description $Title `
    -Company $Company `
    -EmailAddress $EmailAddress `
    -StreetAddress $StreetAddress `
    -City $City `
    -State $State `
    -PostalCode $PostalCode `
    -Country $Country `
    -OtherAttributes $proxyAddress `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
    -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
    -Enabled $true `

I have tried escaping the -Name attribute but can't get it to work, probably because I have a mental block for how to implement it.

"since -Name sets the name and displayName attributes" - that's only the case when you omit -DisplayName, which you don't. Easiest solution here is to pass -Name $Username -DisplayName $Name

Edited my question since I realized I set -DisplayName as $Name (why I duplicated variables I'm not sure, probably for consistency even though it was unnecessary). Still hoping to keep my 'name' attribute consistent with the rest of my users when it's set by powershell.

That ship has obviously sailed, since you won't be able to set the object name to the same as the display name :)

Welp, I'll leave this question up for posterity and future readers, but I think I have stumbled across the real issue which is unrelated to hyphens in names. I believe it's a sAMAccountName issue since those are limited to 20 characters and hyphenating the name I'm trying to enter (or any name that exceeds 20 characters) produces that 'not properly formed account name' error. Shorten the name using a hyphen and no error.

I'd strongly suggest going back and reviewing the real-life process you're trying to automate here. How would you decide on a username if you were to do it manually? How do you handle hyphens in the names of existing users, how do you deal with apostrophes? Surname prefixes? Postnomials? What about collisions? If 2 John Smith's join, what username does the second one get? Is reuse allowed? Write down the answers to these, and any other relevant questions regarding usernames. Now you have a specification for a New-Username function that'll pick a valid account name based on the input :)
